# CXF Client Webservice Ping has thrown exception Could not send Message. Invalid address. Endpoint address cannot be null

Tags: cxf

I am getting the following error [1] from the following code:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URL WSDL_LOCATION=null;
        if ( null == cl ) cl = SQLService.class.getClassLoader();
         WSDL_LOCATION = cl.getResource( "SQLServiceSoap.wsdl" );

        QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://localhost:8080/gateway/services/SQLServiceSoap?wsdl", "SQLService");
        Service service = Service.create(WSDL_LOCATION,SERVICE_NAME);
        SOAPport sqlService = service.getPort(SOAPport.class);
  Client client = org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(sqlService);
  Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
        Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION,
    WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
  outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, soapUser);
  outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
  outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS,
    PasswordCallbackHandler.class.getName());
  outProps.put("password", soapPass);
  WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
  cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

  String result = sqlService.ping("test");
  LOG.warn("PONG!: " + result);
```

My unfamiliarity with webservices continues to cause me grief.

[1]WARNING: Interceptor for {http://localhost:8080/gateway/services/SQLServiceSoap?wsdl}SQLService#{http://gateway.sf.net/sql}Ping has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:48)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:484)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:310)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:262)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
        at $Proxy37.ping(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.base.sql.SQLClientBase.setSecurityHeaderTokens(SQLClientBase.java:255)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.base.sql.SQLClientBase.get(SQLClientBase.java:289)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.module.sql.SQLModule.getBatch(SQLModule.java:149)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.module.sql.SQLModule.getAndProcessSQL(SQLModule.java:110)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.module.sql.SQLModule.run(SQLModule.java:280)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.GatewayClient.exec(GatewayClient.java:399)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.GatewayClient.run(GatewayClient.java:174)
        at net.sf.gateway.client.GatewayClient.main(GatewayClient.java:166)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Invalid address. Endpoint address cannot be null.
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.getURL(HTTPConduit.java:833)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.getURL(HTTPConduit.java:815)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.setupURL(HTTPConduit.java:741)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.prepare(HTTPConduit.java:496)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:46)

Comment: It's not your unfamiliarity with webservices, it's the simple fact that the way Spring/CXF was designed (DI) is violating a very fundamental rule in the world of software development: It defers error detection to runtime instead of build/compile time. See? Class factories gives you lots of flexibility & power, but this doesn't come without a price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End point was not setup at all, and CXF does not configure your End Point for you if it is different than what you have in your WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

please
Check the route to wsdl file